# Where do I find the 13F form?

Tags: stocks

I'm reading [this article](https://equalocean.com/briefing/20210814230069306) and it says:

> According to the 13F document of Goldman Sachs in the second quarter,
> the bank bought 5.87 million Alibaba shares in the second quarter,
> making Alibaba its fifth largest holding stock. In addition,
> technology stocks such as apple, Facebook and Tesla also received a
> significant increase. As of the second quarter, Goldman's top five
> positions were S & P 500 ETF, apple, Microsoft, ASUS Russell 2000 ETF
> and Alibaba.

I understand the 13F form is flawed, but I still want a look at the list.

All I found is this one: https://13f.info/13f/000076999321000319-goldman-sachs-group-inc-q3-2021 , a third-party website.

Since Form-13F is not available on the [goldman sachs's website](https://www.goldmansachs.com/investor-relations/financials/index.html). Does anyone know the source of these structured data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [SEC](https://www.investor.gov/introduction-investing/investing-basics/glossary/form-13f-reports-filed-institutional-investment), you have to use the EDGAR website:

`You can search for and retrieve Form 13F filings using the SEC's EDGAR database. To find the filings of a particular money manager, enter the money manager's name in the Company Name field. To see all recently filed 13Fs, use the "Latest Filings" search function and enter "13F" in the Form Type box.`